# Tarantool master-master replication

Tags: nosql, replication, tarantool

I had cluster with two nodes in replica set (master and replica).
How should I configure replication master-master?
I tried change flag read_only on replica, but it isn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `all_rw` replicaset parameter; it is available via both UI and API.